# I can`t run ipython on cmd on windows seven

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, ipython

I installed `ipython` with `pip` command on my terminal but if I type `ipython` in cmd This error occurs:

```
'ipython' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/what-is-the-reason-for-x-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ipython` likely isn't installed in your `PATH`. The simplest approach here is to use [the Python launcher for Windows](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) to launch it via the installed module (which Python knows where to find, without the OS needing to find it), e.g.:

```
py -3 -mIPython
```

should launch the installed IPython for the most recent version of Python 3 installed on your machine. The `-3` specifies that you want Python 3 (the latest) while `-m` is a general Python switch that means "run the provided module name as the main entry point for this program, looking it up as per normal import rules".